# Azure AD B2B authentication - dynamic trusted issuers for multi-tenant applications

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm converting a web application to enable Azure AD B2B collaboration.

Currently it is authenticating internal organisation users via Azure AD (V2 Microsoft Graph API) and is validating the token issuer like this:

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = validIssuer
                },
```

The valid issuer is coming from a static web.config setting.

The above works fine if you're dealing with static tenants, i.e. only users from A,B,C organisations should be able to access the application.

In my scenario I'm looking to have a dynamic list of domains (contoso.com, xyz.com, etc.) from which users can authenticate.

I understand that this can be handled at application level by checking the token's claims and looking if the username domain matches the application's white-listed domains. However, I'm interested if I can delegate this validation to either:

- the authentication pipeline (validating issuers)
- at Azure AD level (meaning the users will not even reach the application if they're not coming from the approved domains). This would be ideal.